# Почему mock объект не ведет себя в соответствии с when().then()?

Tags: java, hibernate, юнит-тесты, mockito, mocking

Есть метод который достает данные из базы при помощи Hibernate:

```
public Task getById(final Integer id) {
    Task result;

    final String hql = format(
            "select t from Task t where t.id = %s", id.toString());

    try (final Session session = factory.get().openSession()) {

        session.beginTransaction();
        final Query query = session.createQuery(hql); //Вот тут проблема.
        final List list = query.list();

        result = (Task)list.get(0);

        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Но, когда я пытаюсь его тестировать то мне не удается создать mock объект для `Query query = session.createQuery(hql)` Так как объект `session` возвращает мне `null` не смотря на то что я явно указываю поведение при помощи `when(session.createQuery(hql)).thenReturn(query)`.

Вот тест:

```
private static AtomicReference<SessionFactory> factory;
private static Session session;
private static Transaction transaction;
private static final Task task = new Task(3, "test",
        new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()), false);

@BeforeClass
public static void before() {
    final SessionFactory fac = mock(SessionFactory.class);
    session = mock(Session.class);
    when(fac.openSession()).thenReturn(session);

    factory = new AtomicReference<>(fac);

    transaction = mock(Transaction.class);
    when(session.getTransaction()).thenReturn(transaction);
}

@Test
public void getByIdTest() {
    final DAO<Task, Integer> dao = new TaskDAO(factory);
    final Task result = dao.getById(1);

    final String hql = String.format("select t from Task t where t.id = %s", "1");

    final Query query = mock(Query.class);
    when(session.createQuery(hql)).thenReturn(query);//Вот это строка не работает.

    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add(task);
    when(query.list()).thenReturn(list);

    Assert.assertThat(result, is(task));
    verify(factory.get()).openSession();
}
```

Как мне задать поведение для `session.createQuery(hql)`?

Comment: Не по теме, но: не нужно такой код тестировать юнит-тестами. Интеграционные тесты вам в помощь.

Comment: @andreycha ну почему же не по теме очень даже по теме...

Comment: Ну вы ж про странное поведение mockito спрашиваете, а я вам совсем про другое :). Некоторые просто не любят подобные ответы. Могу оформить более развернутым ответом, если хотите.

Comment: @andreycha да если не трудно буду признателен.

Comment: Ответил. Прошу прощения за задержку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы сказал, что такой код вообще не нужно покрывать юнит-тестами. Работу DAL'а лучше проверять нормальными интеграционными тестами, при участии БД. Попробую объяснить, почему.

Юнит-тестам предназначены для тестирования логики в отсутствии внешних зависимостей.

В методе, который вы хотите протестировать, логика отсутствует. Все, что проверяет тест `getByIdTest` -- это то, что метод вернет некоторый объект и, косвенно, что будет выполнен корректный запрос. При этом тест не проверяет, например, что транзакция будет начата и закоммичена, а соединение в любом случае будет закрыто.

Большую часть теста представляет собой настройка тех самых внешних зависимостей. Такой тест далек от принципа тестирования черного ящика, т.е. он становится хрупким, подверженным падениям и изменениям.

Подобный код лучше всего покрывать интеграционными тестами (они вам все равно рано или поздно понадобятся). С их помощью вы избавитесь от необходимости ручного тестирования взаимодействия с БД, а заодно и от "некошерных" юнит-тестов.

В случае же с Hibernate возможно пойти на компромиссный вариант. Насколько я помню, с ним можно использовать in-memory заглушку для БД. Т.е., с одной стороны, вы пишете полноценный интеграционный тест на DAL, а с другой стороны избавляетесь от использования внешних зависимостей (реальной БД).